# Why do a bitwise and?

Tags: c#, bitwise-and

**There is no problem with the code I'm just curious.** I have this code I'm looking at and I'm trying to figure out why they do bitwise and and not just a regular &&

```
bool bValid = true;
.... // some code here
bValid &= IsASMConfigurationValid(this.m_ThisDevices[BDCASM], ref el);
.... // more code here
bValid &= IsSPEConfigurationValid(this.m_ThisDevices[BDCSPE], ref el);
```

I just want to know why this did this instead of just setting bValid = to IsConfigValid. This could very well be just his coding style.

Comment: If that's your only problem with this code...

Comment: There is no "bitwise AND" for boolean values, there is "non-shortcircuiting" one... So not clear what is your problem with that...

Comment: [Here's some good info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) on the difference between `&&` and `&` when it comes to Booleans.

Comment: Sequential updating of a flag? If any of those IsASM calls returns false, then bValid becomes false and STAYS false

Comment: I would suggest not using GoTo in your code, its very messy and its hard to trace. && is a comparison/condition, & is a bitwise operator

Comment: Every time I see a `GOTO`, I think of *Intercal* which was *so against* GOTO they implemented its polar opposite, the `COME FROM` command.

Comment: Relax guys, OP mentions this is not his code. Let's not assume he's some `goto` loving pervert.

Comment: Josh Davis, please try to spend first several minutes after asking the question in browser watching for comments. Noone really should be touching your code sample except you, but I had to do that as current discussion about "goto" is way off-topic from you actual question. Please take time and make sure my edit reflects your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see some options:

- Lazyness - why type bValid again? Lets just use the `&=` to avoid writing it again.
- Optimization - bValid is only evaluated once (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx)
- Randomness

Remember that there is no bitwise operation for `bool` operand, so its just a logical AND.

All are very personal, the best answer will come from the real developer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just look at this line:

`bValid &= IsSPEConfigurationValid(this.m_ThisDevices[BDCSPE], ref el);`

This could be rewritten as:

`bValid = bValid && IsSPEConfigurationValid(this.m_ThisDevices[BDCSPE], ref el);`

or

`if(bValid) { 
   bValid = IsSPEConfigurationValid(this.m_ThisDevices[BDCSPE], ref el); 
}`

...or other similar forms.  The `&=` makes the code shorter by a few characters but, as you've found, mainly just makes it harder to read.

UPDATE: as commenters pointed out, &= doesn't short circuit for bools like && does so the real alternative that still invokes the function on the right would be:

`var temp = IsSPEConfigurationValid(this.m_ThisDevices[BDCSPE], ref el);
bValid = bValid && temp`

Comment: I would say the only reason using `&=` would make a difference, is if `IsSPEConfigurationValid` has some side effects, and the developer needed it to run even if `bValid` was false at this point. Which, in itself would be a code smell.

Comment: "This could be rewritten as ... && " - there is a huge difference between 2 lines - your code will not run the function for `bValid == false` case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The use of `&&` her would also mean that `bValid` would be evaluated *twice* no matter what, in addition to the second operand possibly being short circuited.

Comment: @RobertLevy Your attempts to short circuit the second operand resulted in you writing code that forces the evaluation of that expression, given that you refactored it out to a variable.

Comment: @Servy Good point, but I would be really concerned if "evaluated twice" for non-volatile boolean variable (as in OP's sample) really cause any changes...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In this case, no, in the general case, quite possibly.

Answer (score 0):

So, first off, there is no bitwise operator used here.  The `&` operator has several overloads; it has both a number of bitwise overloads for numeric types, but it also has an overload for boolean values that performs a *logical* AND that simply doesn't short circuit.

As to why the code author didn't use the `&&=` operator instead of the `&=` operator, that would be *because there is no `&&=` operator*, only a `&=` operator.